# HTML Dec Code image in Tkinter label — either text or image is doubled

Tags: html, python-3.x, tkinter

I'd like to add a picture to some of my `tkinter` labels, and I found a [page with many of them](https://www.alt-codes.net/flags) (there are, of course, many similar pages), including some that I want.
But I'm having a strange behavior with this.
The code

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import html

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

s = html.unescape('&#127937')  # chequered flag
text = "some text"
label_text = "{}{}".format(text, s)

my_label = ttk.Label(root, text=label_text)
my_label.pack()

t = chr(9917)
another = "football ball"
another_text = "{}{}".format(t, another)

another_label = ttk.Label(root, text=another_text)
another_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

produces the following window:

[image]

On the other hand, if I replace `label_text = "{}{}".format(text, s)` with `label_text = "{}{}".format(s, text)` the flag appears twice instead (once before "some text" and another after).

Apparently this only happens with html images.
For example, with the second label, I have the expected behavior.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here, or should I just avoid these images in `tkinter`?

Comment: I'm not sure how should I have tagged this question. Perhaps the `html` tag isn't appropriated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wouldnt avoid them yet i wouldnt advise them either. Because tkinter propbably uses regular images its propbably not used to emojis. My recommendation is to use regular images instead of emojis.